# Нелинейное изменение размеров блока

Tags: html, css, html5

Каким образом можно задать нелинейной изменение ширины? Мне требуется, чтобы ширина менялась примерно так:

1280 -> 100%, 1580 -> 70%, 1980 -> 50%, 2384 -> 40%, 2680 -> 35%

Такое отображение (f: пиксели -> процент от ширины родителя) я примерно смогу руками подобрать. Сигмоида какая-нибудь, например.

Т.е. мне хотелось бы встроить в css функцию, которая вычисляет ширину так, как мне хочется.

Comment: javascript только - или с `calc` париться

Comment: @MaximLensky Я знаю про media, но это выглядит жутким костылём. Чем может обернуться интеграция css и js? Как это грамотно сделать?

Comment: я не совсем понимаю о чём речь - в чём менять ширину

Comment: @MaximLensky В пикселях, в процентах. Какая разница в чём?

Comment: вы щас о блоке говорите - вы говорите о изменении ширины блока ?

Comment: @MaximLensky да

Comment: тогда пишите кучу запросов под каждую величину - в css

Comment: @MaximLensky Выглядит как костыль (=

Comment: в css вообще костылей мало ..я вообще не понимаю что значит костыль ..

Comment: это называется медиа запросы - как раз для этого предназначены - кастыль - это когда не работает в IE11 но надо что бы заработало